# How to create a searchable list

Tags: android

I would like to have a database of items stored on the user's phone. I currently have everything set up using WebView pointed at my domain, but obviously this isn't ideal if the user is in a low-signal location.

If possible I would also like to be able to search the list for multiple words.

Any pointers to tutorials etc would be ideal.

Comment: OR Alternatively I would like to get the information to create the list from an RSS/XML feed with the search query inserted into the URL (i.e. http://mysite.co.uk/Search_Query/feed.rss). Is this possible? If so how? Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android you'll want to use SQLite databases, here are some places from where I learned my way with databases in Android:

Start here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android

Or here if you want to use an existing database:
http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

---

If you decide on XML, though, you might want to read this instead:

http://www.anddev.org/parsing_xml_from_the_net_-_using_the_saxparser-t353.html

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-xml-parsing-tutorial-using-saxparser

---

Here you have a tutorial involving both methods, downloading data in XML format, parsing it and storing the information on a database, probably the guide you want to read if you're starting with Android, since it covers pretty much what you are trying to achieve, probably :P

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-fundamentals-downloading-data-with-services/

Comment: Thanks, havent been through them yet but sounds like what i want to do!